# Change placeholder colour

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

I used this code to change my placeholder colour but it's not working.

I used this method in category.

```
 -(void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
    [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
}
error:
Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its :
```

'drawInRect:withFont:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use -drawInRect:withAttributes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
[[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect
                withAttributes:@{
                                 NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16],
                                 NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor], //Font Color
                                 }];
```

instead of 'drawInRect:withFont:'

*Attributes is a NSDictionary with the attributes that you want, and there you can specify which font you want, among another stuff, like color, etc.

Comment: i like to change font colour help me to do that but above code is used properly.show some coding to change font color.

Comment: I edited the code above with font color (NSForegroundColorAttributeName) 
Cheers